# Still no async methods after EntityFramework update 6.0 to 6.1.3?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I have a ASP.NET MVC4 that talks to a database via EntityFramework 6.0. The DbContext was created using the EDMX designer with database-first. The application is aiming at .NET Framework 4.0.

In order to be able to use the new async methods like `.FirstOrDefaultAsync()` I tried to upgrade EF to the current stable version 6.1.3.

So I ran `Update-Package EntityFramework` in the Nuget console. It took some seconds, no error messages appeared and the installation ended with:

```
Successfully installed 'EntityFramework 6.1.3' to MyProject
```

After that, I ran ***Build --> Clean Solution*** and then rebuild everything. Next, I made sure that my controller contains these *using* statements (besides others):

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

However, I still can't use any async methods, they're simply not found. Here's an example:

```
using (MyEntities db = new MyEntities())
{
    var dp = await db.DataPoints.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == DataPointId);
}
```

***FirstOrDefaultAsync*** is marked as faulty by Intellisense, when trying to build anyway I get this error:

```
'DbSet<DataPoint>' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefaultAsync' and no extension method 'FirstOrDefaultAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'DbSet<DataPoint>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

What can I do to resolve this issue? Which actions need to be taken? Thanks for your help!

Comment: What .NET version are you targeting?

Comment: Target .NET version is 4.0.

Comment: Nope. 4.0 has no async support, you know. Update to.... 4.5, i think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to uninstall all your NuGet packages, change your target .NET version to 4.5 or higher, and then reinstall all your NuGet packages.

Then open `web.config` and then [set the `targetFramework` attribute of the `httpRuntime` element](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework/) to the version that you're targeting.

Comment: Go to 4.6.x or 4.5.2, the support for 4.5.x is already ending.

Comment: That did it, thanks. I went straight for 4.6.1 (thanks, Henk). You need to run *Update-Package -reinstall [PackageName]* for each package.